# how to escape `<p>\$\{erro\}</p>` in snippets in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to escape the characters $, {and} in the code snippet `<p> $ {error} </ p>` but the code.snippets editor of vs code shows me an error message.
Can anybody help me?

[The error message is the red squiggly underline signifying an "Invalid escape character in string."]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you post the error message given by vs code?

Comment: wrap it with quotes. `<p> "$ {error}" </ p>`

Comment: Also what kind of file is this. Provide more context

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<p>\\${erro}</p>
```

if you want to end up with:

```
<p>${erro}</p>
```

(Sometimes I just keep adding backslashes until the errors go away ;>}).  The $ has to be escaped because it otherwise can trigger a placeholder reference. The {}s don't have to escaped.